# Можно ли использовать fstream для чтения файлов в Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, fstream

Обязательно ли использовать Qfile и QTextStream для чтения файлов в qt или можно fstream? И ещё правильно ли сначала забирать значение с помощью string, а потом конвертировать их в QString?

Comment: Зачем Вам `fstream`? В Qt средства работы с файлами куда удобнее, чем в стандартной библиотеке.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чем меньше в программе намешано технологий, тем проще ее в дальнейшем сопровождать. Да и при использовании `QFile` можно получать сразу значения в типах `Qt`.

Если же намешать `std` и `Qt`, появится так называемый `glue-code` - процедуры конверсии типов данных между библиотеками.